# How to store integers into an array in C++?

Tags: c++

My program will take a line like: 1, 5, 6, 7
Then it will store each integer into an array.

I think, at first input should take as string. But how could I split this by comma & space separator? Then how it will store in array as an integer?

Answer (score 5):

For splitting you can use [`std::string::find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find) and [`std::string::substr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr). Call e.g. `str.find(", ")` in a loop, splitting the string with `substr`.

For storage you shoudln't use an array, you should use [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

To convert the sub-strings to integers, see e.g. [`std::stoi`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol).

Answer (score 1):

In addition to *Joachim*'s answer (and given that your question wasn't tagged C++11 by accident), the most general approach would probably be to use regular expressions:

```
#include <regex>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

std::vector<int> parse(const std::string &str)
{
    //is it a comma-separated list of positive or negative integers?
    static const std::regex valid("(\\s*[+-]?\\d+\\s*(,|$))*");
    if(!std::regex_match(str, valid))
        throw std::invalid_argument("expected comma-separated list of ints");

    //now just get me the integers
    static const std::regex number("[+-]?\\d+");
    std::vector<int> vec;
    std::transform(std::sregex_iterator(str.begin(), str.end(), number), 
                   std::sregex_iterator(), std::back_inserter(vec), 
                   [](const std::smatch &m) { return std::stoi(m.str()); });
    return vec;
}
```

It can be adapted to your needs, e.g. if you want only positive numbers, only a single space after each comma, or no space before the comma, but the overall approach should be clear. But this whole thing may be overkill for your particular need and *Joachim*'s approach of manual parsing may be better suited.